# Can you resurface concrete treated with silane siloxane?

Tags: concrete, sealant, resurfacing

Concrete Sealant Manufacturers claim that remove silane siloxane sealer from concrete is very hard to do and not recommended since the product penetrates deeply into concrete and chemically reacts with it. At the same time resurface concrete products ask you to remove concrete sealant.

So it looks like once you apply this sealant you won't be able to resurface concrete anymore. That would make application of sealant a very dumb idea. Is there any solution to that conundrum.  Am I missing something ?

Comment: If you apply the sealer, and it works as advertised, why would you need to resurface the concrete?

Comment: how about flame thrower

Comment: Cracks by soil movement, heavy things falling into it and what if the sealant is not good enough. Looks like it is  a one way ticket. Once you put it, it is better work because resurface is not an option anymore.

Comment: Can ask the sealer makers about resurfacing or use a bit on some broken concrete and test yourself.  That or use a sealer that is easier to remove.